# 1004 error (select method of range class failed)

Tags: excel, vba, methods, range

I am currently working on a tool, getting some data but not the formula or other format. Just the plain text. However it gives me the error of 1004.

here's my code:

```
Sub WBS()
    Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range

    Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("totalcosts.xlsm").Worksheets(3).Range("A3:A300")
    Set targetColumn = Workbooks("Backing sheet.xlsm").Worksheets(2).Range("C6:C300")

    sourceColumn.Copy
    targetColumn.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Call Resource_Name
End Sub
```

It always give me error on the *targetcolumn.select*

But when I use this code to copy and paste on the line,

```
*"sourceColumn.Copy destination=targetcolumn"*
```

It paste the data that I need. However it copies the formula instead of the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cut your destination down to a single cell (top-left) and let the paste operation fill the remainder.

```
Sub WBS()
    Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range

    Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("totalcosts.xlsm").Worksheets(3).Range("A3:A300")
    Set targetColumn = Workbooks("Backing sheet.xlsm").Worksheets(2).Range("C6")

    sourceColumn.Copy
    targetColumn.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
                              SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Call Resource_Name
End Sub
```

Use the [Range.PasteSpecial method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx) directly off the target range. There is no need to [Range .Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197597.aspx) method it first¹.

Since you are only transferring the [Range.Value property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx), a direct value transfer would be the better option.

```
Sub WBS()
    Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range

    Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("totalcosts.xlsm").Worksheets(3).Range("A3:A300")
    Set targetColumn = Workbooks("Backing sheet.xlsm").Worksheets(2).Range("C6")

    with sourceColumn
        targetColumn.Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
    end with

    Call Resource_Name
End Sub
```

---

¹ <sub>See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for more methods on getting away from relying on select and activate to accomplish your goals.</sub>

Comment: what I did is just remove the targetcolumn.select :)

Comment: Yes, you cannot use the [Range .Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197597.aspx) method on a cell that is not in the [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). You were probably focused on the worksheet holding the `sourceColumn` cells. Best practise is to avoid it unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: hello jeeped thank you very much.. but I have added some question above :) I hope you can help me too with that :)

Comment: I believe this question should be left closed off and you can start a new question with the updated information and new inquiry. See [Etiquette for Russian Doll Questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625/etiquette-for-russian-doll-questions).

Comment: im so sorry I did not know that rules in here :( BTW I already removed the added querry. Thanks again for answering :)